# IIS com asp.net core 2.0 - Erro 502.5? O IIS não está reconhecendo o asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

Estou com o projeto no pc, e o mesmo no computador dos colegas roda com o `IIS`.
Porém no meu pc, ele não roda, dá o erro `HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure`

Gerei o log do erro:

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Projeto.Api.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup', version: '2.1.0'
    path: 'lib/netcoreapp2.1/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup.dll'
```

Já instalei:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso fazer? Como resolver o problema?

Comment: Tenta dar um dotnet restore antes de publicar.

Comment: Quando publica funciona, só não roda o projeto em edição.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Para corrigir esse erro foi feito os seguintes passos:*

**Instale as versões do:**
(https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core) .NET Core 2.1

**Build apps** - SDK : dotnet-sdk-2.1.402-win-x64

**Run apps** - Runtime : dotnet-hosting-2.1.11-win

**No Visual Studio, verifique se os Componentes Individuais relacionadas ao Net.Core (C#) estão instaladas:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após esses passos, rodou ok.